# How do you retrieve a list of google services with their friendly name in a single request

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-platform, google-api-python-client

I'm trying to get a list of available services including their 'friendly name' with a single request. Below is the code I'm using

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
sm = build('servicemanagement', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

req = sm.services().list(**kwargs)

services = req.execute()

print(services)
```

After some debugging, that appears to perform the following create the following HttpRequest

```
{
  "uri": "https:\/\/servicemanagement.googleapis.com\/v1\/services?alt=json",
  "method": "GET",
  "body": null,
  "headers": {
    "accept": "application\/json",
    "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate",
    "user-agent": "google-api-python-client\/1.6.5 (gzip)"
  },
  "methodId": "servicemanagement.services.list",
  "resumable": null,
  "response_callbacks": [

  ],
  "_in_error_state": false,
  "body_size": 0,
  "resumable_uri": null,
  "resumable_progress": 0
}
```

and returns the following data:

```
{
  "services": [
    {
      "serviceName": "youtube.googleapis.com"
    },
    {
      "serviceName": "monitoring.googleapis.com"
    },
    [...]
```

However, using the following gcloud command, it appears to make the same request and return more data:

```
$ gcloud services list --available --log-http 
=======================
==== request start ====
uri: https://servicemanagement.googleapis.com/v1/services?alt=json
method: GET
== headers start ==
Authorization: xxx
accept: application/json
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
content-length: 0
user-agent: google-cloud-sdk xxx gcloud/184.0.0 [...]
== headers end ==
== body start ==

== body end ==
==== request end ====
---- response start ----
-- headers start --
-content-encoding: gzip
alt-svc: hq=":443"; ma=2592000; quic=51303431; quic=51303339; quic=51303338; quic=51303337; quic=51303335,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="41,39,38,37,35"
cache-control: private
content-length: 28924
content-location: https://servicemanagement.googleapis.com/v1/services?alt=json
content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
date: Fri, 26 Jan 2018 21:01:58 GMT
server: ESF
status: 200
transfer-encoding: chunked
vary: Origin, X-Origin, Referer
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
-- headers end --
-- body start --
{
  "services": [
    {
      "serviceName": "youtube.googleapis.com",
      "serviceConfig": {
        "name": "youtube.googleapis.com",
        "title": "YouTube Data API v3",
        "documentation": {
          "summary": "The YouTube Data API v3 is an API that provides access to YouTube data, such as videos, playlists, and channels."
        },
        "legacy": {
          "apiV1Name": "youtube",
          "devconsole": {
            "learnmoreUrl": "https://developers.google.com/youtube/",
            "requestQuotaUrl": "https://services.google.com/fb/forms/ytapiquotarequest/",
            "consoleApi": "NEW"
          }
        },
        "usage": {
          "requirements": [
            "serviceusage.googleapis.com/tos/youtube"
          ],
          "serviceAccess": "PUBLIC"
        },
        "id": "2016-09-14r0",
        "migration": {}
      }
```

Comment: Is there a question here? You seem to have and executed the needed command already...

Comment: I want to be able to get the same output shown via the gcloud command, with the google api client. From what I can tell the http requests are identical, but the responses are not the same. The API client returns just the serviceName, but the gcloud command returns additional serviceConfig for each service.

Comment: What do you get when you use the REST API instead of the api client? It could very well be that the api client doesn't support interpreting that part of the response.

Comment: Same thing result as the api client library:

```[jceresini@marvin ~]$ curl -H 'Authorization: Bearer [access-token]' https://servicemanagement.googleapis.com/v1/services?alt=json
{
  "services": [
    {
      "serviceName": "youtube.googleapis.com"
    },
    {
      "serviceName": "monitoring.googleapis.com"
    },
    {
      "serviceName": "toolresults.googleapis.com"
    }...```

Comment: So the gcloud command appears to be doing something different, but using the --log-http flag doesn't seem show me what it is. If you look at the output, it shows the url it hits, the request method, the headers, etc... but the response from the api is different.